# Using least squares to estimate mean

Tags: regression, least-squares

From *"Generalized Additive Models: an introduction with R" by Simon N. Wood, page 55, Exercise 1.9, Question 1*:

> 4 car journeys in London of length 1, 3, 4 and 5 kilometres took 0.1,
>   0.4, 0.5 and 0.6 hours respectively. Find a least squares estimate of the mean journey speed.

*Hint: use a simple one parameter linear model, with journey time as
the response (y) variable and journey length as the predictor (x) variable, think about the meaning of the parameter.*

The answer given at the back of the book is: $\frac{51}{6.3}\approx8.1$ kilometres per hour.

**Question: is that answer correct? It seems to me that it is stated in squared kilometres per hour. Why not $\frac{\sqrt{51}}{6.3}\approx1.13356$ kilometres per hour?**

---

My working:

This is a no intercept linear model because at time zero no distance will have been covered.

$y_i=\beta x_i+\epsilon_i$

Using ordinary least squares regression I can obtain an estimate of $\beta$:

$\hat{\beta}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^4{x_iy_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2}=\frac{(1)(0.1)+(3)(0.4)+(4)(0.5)+(5)(0.6)}{1^2+3^2+4^2+5^2}=\frac{6.3}{51}=0.1235294$

So the model is:

$y_i=0.1235x_i$

Which means a one kilometre change in $x_i$ results in a 0.1235 time change in $y_i$.

This is where I start to get confused.

The total distance covered by the four cars is $\sum_{i=1}^4{x_i}=13$ kilometres.

The total squared distances covered by the four cars is $\sum_{i=1}^4{x_i^2}=51$ kilometres$^2$.

The total time taken by these four cars is $\sum_{i=1}^4{y_i}=1.6$ hours.

As we are told to use least squares, we should then surly do:

$\frac{\sqrt{51}}{1.6}\approx 4.46$ kilometres per hour

I'm guessing I'm probably wrong would appreciate an explanation :)

EDIT: Made correction based on @Whuber's comment

Comment: **Let's do a reality check**: the data reflect journeys with mean speeds of 1 km/0.1 hr = 10 kph, 3 km/0.4 hr = 7.5 kph, 4 km/0.5 hr = 8 kph, and 5 km/0.6 hr = 8.33 kph. This range of speeds from 7.5 to 10 kph shows that an answer of 1.13 kph is grossly wrong and that 8.1 kph is reasonable. Moreover, the total distance is 1+3+4+5=13 km, not 6.3 km, in a period of 0.1+0.4+0.5+0.6=1.6 hours.

Comment: @whuber you comment makes sense to me, and 13/1.6 = 8.1 kph so that would be the correct answer and I can see why my answer would be way off. But *why* in the solution is it 51/6.3?

Comment: Where did your last formula come from? You could have stopped after "So the model is," noting that $0.1235$ hr/km is saying the same thing as $1/0.1235 = 8.10$ km/hr. The subtle point here is that this is *not* a "least squares estimate" of *speed*: it is a *transformed* estimate of the reciprocal of speed. A least squares estimate of speed has to be obtained by regressing distance against time, not time against distance. (The answers will be close in this example, but they do differ: you would get $8.08$ kph.) Thus the exercise is misleading (at best).

Comment: In writing these comments and seeing your edits, it occurs to me you would benefit from a more careful analysis of the units of measurement.  You have given $\sum x_i^2$ as squared kilometers, which is correct.  What are the units in $\sum x_i y_i$?  What are the units in your last formula that yields $4.46$?  (Hint: they are *not* km/hr.)

Comment: @whuber I made the last formula myself thinking that it would get me away from squared km/hr ($\frac{51}{1.6}=31.875$ km$^2$/hr vs $\frac{\sqrt{51}}{1.6}=4.46$ km/hr). I can't see how 4.46 is not km/hr to be honest? $\sum_{i=1}^4{x_iy_i}$ would be the sum of distance x time, so the units would be...er, I'm not sure what you'd call that (it's not speed)... :S ...BTW, your second comment makes beautiful sense to me and I can see why the solution is arrived at in the book.

Comment: $\sum x_i y_i = 6.3$ has units of km-hours while $\sum x_i^2 = 51$ has units of squared km, whence its square root is in km.  Dividing by the former tells us that $4.46$ is a value *per hour* (no kilometers are involved at all). That's a clear indication this formula is incorrect.  Without the square root, the units are $51/6.3$ km^2 / (km-hr) = km/hr, which is a speed. I don't know why you were attempting to take the square root in the first place, though.

Comment: I fully understand now, thanks! I didn't take into account that 6.3 was in units of km-hr. I can see the km unit cancellation that takes place in km^2 / (km-hr) = km/hr, hence there's no reason to take the square root. I think this has been a great lesson in paying closer attention to what the units are.